# Paloalto:Same segment but different zones

Tags: palo-alto

I am a novice and I don't have a paloalto at hand.
I don't know if it is possible that two devices communicate each other one of which belongs to Trust Zone and the other belongs to DMZ Zone.
However, two devices are in the same segment like 192.168.100.10/24(Trust) and 192.168.100.20/24(DMZ).

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

That’s an invalid configuration. You can’t have two zones (and interfaces) in the same subnet.

Answer (score 2):

Firewall can ensure connectivity among different zone by framing security policies among different zone and allow communication between different zone

But in your scenario trust zone & DMZ zone is possible to establish connectivity by configuring security policy in palo alto firewall, but both zones ip address  should be in different segment cannot be in same subnet ..